# culling meshes across mulitple layers

Tags: opengl, algorithm, 3d, transformations, bounding-volume-hierarchy

I am implementing foveated rendering. My [FBO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) is divided into 2 layers which are concentric. The first layer covers 1/3 of the Framebuffer whereas the second one covers the rest of the screen. Now I want to avoid rendering meshes in the outer layer which are already in the inner layer.

I have implemented the following culling algorithm which is only concerned with culling between the layers:

1. I create rectangles with min and max corners from the radii of the 2 layers. Now these coordinates are in [NDC](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Graphics/ndc.shtml).
2. I have the min and max corner of each mesh in the local coordinate system. So I transform them into NDC using:

   ```
   vec4 min = mvp * vec4(min_corner, 1.0);
   min = min.xyzw / min.w;
   ```
3. I create a bounding box using min and max corners.
4. I check whether 2 rectangles overlap or not.

Now, when I transform into clip space, the x or y coordinates of the min are sometimes greater than the max corner. The same issue occurs when I divide them by w. What's going wrong here?

EDIT:
Okay. I found the problem. Now I iterate over all the vertices, transform each of them into NDC using [MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550620/the-purpose-of-model-view-projection-matrix) and then calculate the min and max corners which works perfect. But this is much more overhead for each frame. Is there any optimization I can do here?

Comment: @trichoplax which part of it you did not understand?

Comment: `transform bounding sphere radius and center of sphere in 0-1` doesn't make clear whether you want the radius normalised to 1, or transformed to some value between 0 and 1 (in which case, how is that value determined?). The same for the centre - is it to be moved to the origin or translated to somewhere within a distance 1 from the origin or something else?

Comment: `somebody pointed out to me that its not possible to transform radius into 0-1` From the comments on your [initial question](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/calculate-bounding-sphere-radius-in-normalized-space) it doesn't appear that anyone is saying that it is not possible to transform the radius. We just need to know what you mean by "0-1".

Comment: @trichoplax okay. I changed my algorithm. Can you check it

Comment: This seems clearer now. I've edited to add in links and hovertext for the acronyms. If this changes your intention please edit to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding optimizations:

Could you calculate the min and max corners in modelspace beforehand? Then you could check on the CPU-side the NDCs of these two points and skip the processing of the whole mesh if it is outside of the desired range. This needs only two matrix-vector multiplications on cpu side. And since for rigid bodies these two points do not change over time, you don't have to iterate the meshes in each frame.

Comment: I can not calculate min max corner in modelspace as after multiplying with view and projection matrices, min and max corner does not remains the same. that is why I am iterating over all the vertices.Previously I thought just using bounding box would suffice but looks like it is changing in clip coordinate space.

Comment: when I checked NDC coordinates at the end in both ways, I get very different numbers. with iteration over vertices I get vertex cooridinates in range of minus thousands to plus thousands whereas with bounding boxes they are in range of -10 plus 10 approx.